# how can i add the condition in Batch class

Tags: batch

I have the Sobjects `Sales_Order__c` (SO), `Sales_Order_Line__c` (SOL) , and `Stock__c`. I want to add the following condition in a batch class as
`if (Quantity_Ordered__c) >= Quantity__c` the SO `Ordered_Status__c` should be "Closed".

`Quantity_Ordered__c` - it is in `Sales_Order_Line__c` (object) and `Quantity__c` is in `Stock__c` (object)

Here's what's been tried so far.

```
global class Batchupdate implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {
    global Integer recordsProcessed = 0;  
    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
        String query= 'Select id, Date_Time_Ordered__c,Need_Date__c,Type__c, Order_Status__c from Sales_Order__c';
        return Database.getQueryLocator(query);
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext bc, List<Sales_Order__c> scope){
        List<Sales_Order__c> so=[Select id, Date_Time_Ordered__c,Need_Date__c,Type__c ,Order_Status__c from Sales_Order__c];
        for(Sales_Order__c salesorder: scope){
            salesorder.Order_Status__c ='Closed';
            recordsProcessed = recordsProcessed + 1;
            }
        update scope;
       }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext bc){
    }
}
```

Comment: Is there some identifier for a particular product found in `Stock__c` that can correlate that product to the SOL? Or is there a relationship between the SOL and the Stock object? Some more details about the object model, relationships and such would help you answer this, probably.

Comment: Hi pchittum.                                                                                                         
 Thanks for your response.I have the quantity and product field in **Stock__c**. and the quantity available field in SOL. And also there is no relationship between SOL and Stock object.

Comment: How do you know which stock item to check if there is no relationship? Is there an ID or a lookup or anything? Without some sort of relationship or even structured naming conventions you are going to have a hard time.

Comment: Iam having an Item lookup in stock and sales order line.

Comment: That sounds like a relationship. Unless I'm misunderstanding. This sounds more a question of Apex, SOQL and Data Model than anything related to batch specifically.